# static HashMap is causing the memory leak,but how to rectify it?

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, static, jvm

`private static Map<interface,class> m =new HashMap<interface,class>;`

is an instance variable of a class.

In the constructor of `class  Synchronized(m){m.put(this,this);}`,

The problem is here key and value is same and hence when an updated indication is coming the HAshMap is collecting all the data and it never GC'ed. it is causing leak.

I tried a work around and removed the static keyword and it's working fine.But i think removing static can cause some severe problem.

Is there any other way to rectify this kind of leak. Code refactoring is not possible as it's really complex and i am running out of time. Anyone please guide me. Thanks in Advance

Comment: "m is an instance variable of a class." => no it is a static (or class) variable. Making the map static or not does not have the same meaning at all. Which do you need/want? Why?

Comment: Why do you have the key and value identical in a hash map? Why not just use a `HashSet`?

Comment: Can you show code of your interface class..which you using as key?

Comment: @DougRamsey Actually i am not awre of why they need it like this. But now any way i have to rectify it to resolve the memory leak. Do you suggesting using HashSet instead of HashMap?Does it require more changes?

Comment: Well, Java doesn't "leak memory" so if the objects are not released under pressure then someone - e.g. the HashMap, but could be another collection - is *keeping* the objects Strongly Reachable. While there are various "Weak Reference" HashMaps and such, it likely is just a design issue of not correctly *removing* objects at some point (i.e. when they are no longer relevant/used).

Comment: @Nilamber: Yes it does. A `HashSet` will only have the *key*, although a HashSet is actually backed by a `HashMap` instance. I was really just curious about your design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the hash map is retaining entries you dont want it is because you are not removing them.

There is no particular reason a static collection has to memory leak if you only keep the entries you need.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey So in this case if i use removeAllEntries(this,this);   just below the m.put(this,this); will it work?

Comment: if you use `m.remove(this);` or `m.remove(toBeRemoved);` correctly, you won't have objects you don't want.

Comment: Sir actually the client is getting the updated indication in regular interval.Here the problem is if updated indication came then there is no use of ealier's indications. So i tried as ypu suggested m.remove(this); and checking the memory utilization.Many Thanks.

Comment: Memory utilization is going fine But client doesnot have the problem Creating classes indication now?I am confused if this code handles every indication fine then why a perticular class is creating problem and when i used m.remove(this); then it is not even appearing to the client? Kindly help me out.... Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to WeakHashMap if it fits your use case

Answer (score 0):

In case of Hashmap entry object(entry object stores key-value pairs) is not eligible for garbage collection .In other words, entry object will remain in the memory even if the key object associated with key-value pair is null.

whereas in case of weakhashmap the An entry in a  WeakHashMap will automatically be removed when its key is no longer in ordinary use (even having mapping for a given key will not prevent the key from being discarded by the garbage collector that is made finalizable , finalized and then reclaimed). When a key is discarded then its entry is automatically removed from the map , in other words, garbage collected.

Each key object in the WeakHashMap  is stored indirectly as the referent of a Weak reference(also called hard ) reference.so, a key will automatically be removed only after the weak references to it , both inside and outside of the map , have been cleared by the garbage collector.
Example:
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String, String> map2 = new WeakHashMap<String, String>();
    String hashmapKey = new String("hashmapkey");
    String weakhashmapKey = new String("weakhashmapkey");

    map.put(hashmapKey, "value");
    map2.put(weakhashmapKey, "value");
    System.out.println("Before garbage call");
    System.out.println(map);
    System.out.println(map2);

    hashmapKey = null;
    weakhashmapKey = null;

    System.out.println("After garbage call");
    System.gc();
    System.out.println(map);
    System.out.println(map2);

}
```

**Output:**

Before garbage call
{hashmapkey=value} 
{weakhashmapkey=value} 
After garbage call 
{hashmapkey=value}
{}